# Development environment and AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, firebase, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my Flask application, I have config.py-file that contains database configuration and firebase configuration json that contains all secret keys etc.

How can I use different settings in my local development environment and production AWS EB environment? In local environment I connect to my local database and firebase development instance, in production I want to connect AWS RDS database and firebase production instance.

Is there any ways to change these configs on eb deploy?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use `ENV variables`. (To follow the [12-Factor-App](https://12factor.net/config))

To set `ENV variables` you could use [`eb setenv`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Read more about os and dot_env

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

Here is more detailed documentation https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/